# I need help to extract translations string with REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I have lots of javascript files with translation as string. I want to extract all of them and then generate a translation file. I need help to make the REGEX pattern.

Here some examples that I want to extract.

```
$t('Hello everybody') // extract => Hello everybody
$t("I'm Paul") // extract => I'm Paul
$t("I'm {name}", {name:username}) // extract => I'm {name}
$t('Select {count}', {count: count}) + $t(' element | elements', count) + $t(' on this page')
```

For 4h example, Strings to extract:
Select {count}
 element | elements
 on this page

These strings are in javascript files.
Can you help me to build the REGEX pattern?

Thanks for help.

Comment: It's javascript code.

Comment: I mean what tool are you going to use with these regexps?

Comment: I use Javascript.

Comment: You can try this `^\$t\((['"].*["'])`

Comment: @CodeManiac I tested with the website https://regex101.com/ but your pattern works only with the third example.

Comment: @anardil for me it's working for all three [`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/bW4EwL/1/) all your desired result is in `captured groups`

Comment: @CodeManiac exact, thank you.

Comment: @CodeManiac In fact it doesn't work with the 4th example.

Comment: What do you want to extract in the 4th example ?

Comment: @collapsar I did an update to show you what I want extract for 4th example.

Comment: An elementary regex would be `^\$t\((['"])(.*)\1`, which matches string delimiters (`"`, `'`). The extracted data resides in capture group 2. It will not work on example 4 but it is yet unclear what you want to have extracted. The pattern will also fail if  the string literals contain escaped delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your examples, use the following regex:

```
\$t\((['"])(.*?)\1
```

The extracted data will reside in capture group 2. The pattern fails if the string literals contain escaped delimiters. Note the non-greedy subpattern `.*?` which is essential for example 4.

If you need to take into account escaped delimiters, it complicates the pattern:

```
\$t\((['"])(.*?)(?<!\\)\1
```

A negative lookbehind of the escape symbol `\` prevents the match to terminate at escaped delimiters. Note that escape symbol needs to be escaped. If your regex engine does not support negative lookbehind, you have the option to match an alternating sequence of delimiter-free substrings and escaped delimiters with a negative lookahead preventing premature termination:

```
\$t\((['"])((.*?)(\\\1(.*?))*(?!\\))\1
```

However, expressing the delimiter-free substrings by means of the appropriate character class, you can do away with the negative lookahead as well:

```
\$t\((['"])((.*?)(\\\1([^\\]*?))*)\1
```

Comment: The following would handle escaped delimiters, but you'd have to bother checking if the extracted content is in the first group (single-quotes delimited) or the second (double-quotes delimited) : [`\$t\('((?:\\'|[^'])*)|"((?:\\"|[^"])*)"`](https://regex101.com/r/mWfSTc/1)